# Looping through JS array then ending on a single value permanently

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, sequence, innerhtml

I´m trying to print different sentences inside a DIV on a website.
Im doing this by iterating through an array (wordCycle).
After looping through the array I want *Umdenken.* to be permanently shown.
But instead it loops through the array, then outputs *Umdenken.* and then *undefined* is shown permanently.

This is my code:

```
var wordCycle = [
    'Panierte Schuhsohlen',
    'Essbare Sitzbezüge', 
    'Häuser wie Bäume',
    'Städte wie Wälder',
    'Ein neues Bio', 
    'Masken als Nährstoffe'
];

textSequence(0);
function textSequence(i) {

    if (wordCycle.length > i) {
        setInterval(function () {
            document.getElementById("sequence").innerHTML = wordCycle[i];
            textSequence(++i);
        }, 5500); // in milliseconds (1000 = 1 second)

    } 
    else if (wordCycle.length == i) {
        document.getElementById("sequence").innerHTML = 'Umdenken.';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `setTimeout` to schedule a *single* recursive call, not `setInterval`:

```js
var wordCycle = [
    'Panierte Schuhsohlen',
    'Essbare Sitzbezüge', 
    'Häuser wie Bäume',
    'Städte wie Wälder',
    'Ein neues Bio', 
    'Masken als Nährstoffe'
];

textSequence(0);
function textSequence(i) {

    if (wordCycle.length > i) {
        setTimeout(function () {
            document.getElementById("sequence").innerHTML = wordCycle[i];
            textSequence(++i);
        }, 500); // in milliseconds (1000 = 1 second)

    } 
    else if (wordCycle.length == i) {
        document.getElementById("sequence").innerHTML = 'Umdenken.';
    }
}
```

```html
<div id="sequence"></div>
```

Comment: That worked perfectly, thank you!
Can you tell me how to start with the first sentence without a delay?

Comment: You could have the body of the function set the text immediately, and have the `setTimeout` recursively call the function again (instead of setting the text inside the `setTimeout`). Then the `textSequence(0)` will change the text immediately.